# Changing child-component styles in parent with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the style of the child-component from the parent component

Let's say this is the child component

MyButton.js

```
import ButtonComponent from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const useStyles = makeStyle((theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      color: '#724e35',
    }
  },
  });

  const MyButton = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return <ButtonComponent className={classes.root}>Button</ButtonComponent>
  }

export default MyButton
```

And this is my parent component where I want to change the color of MyButton:

ParentComponent.js

```
import MyButton from './MyButton'

const useStyles = makeStyle((theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      color: '#e1daf9',
    }
  },
  });

  const ParentComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return <MyButton className={classes.root}>Button</MyButton>
  }

export default ParentComponent
```

So the question is: How can I override child style? Neither makeStyles nor classes property work

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyButton` component should accept a `className` prop optionally and include that on its `Button`'s `className`.

```js
const MyButton = ({ className = "" }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={`${classes.root} ${className}`}>Button</Button>;
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-joliot-6q5xn]

Comment: Thanks. I will still have to write styles inside MyButton.js which I am trying to avoid. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you want to override `MyButton.js` style yet you don't want to write a style? I guess that's a different question?

Comment: So let's say that `MyButton` is a reusable component with all the styles I need (like margin, padding, typography, etc) and usually it has a color of #724e35. 

But inside `ParentComponent` I want `MyButton` to have another color, let's say #e1daf9. Can I do it without editing `MyButton.js`?

Comment: I guess not. I'm thinking of giving a known `className` to `MyButton` so that we can override it using css file - but that still changes the `MyButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the overriding class like this

MyButton.js

```
import ButtonComponent from '@material-ui/core/Button'
const useStyles = makeStyle((theme) => {
      return {
        root: {
          color: '#724e35',
        }
      },
      });
    
      const MyButton = ({myButtonStyleOverrideClass = ''}) => {
        const classes = useStyles()
        return <ButtonComponent className={`${classes.root} ${myButtonStyleOverrideClass}`}>Button</ButtonComponent>
      }

export default MyButton
```

ParentComponent.js

```
import MyButton from './MyButton'

const useStyles = makeStyle((theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      color: '#e1daf9',
    }
  },
  });

  const ParentComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return <MyButton myButtonStyleOverrideClass={classes.root}>Button</MyButton>
  }

export default ParentComponent
```